# Jquery countdown progress bar for a coming soon page

Tags: jquery, timer, countdown, progress

I'm looking for a animated jQuery progress bar, horizontal and/or vertical.

Free or commercial one.

The idea is to set the start and end date something like:

```
var startDate = new Date();
var endDate = new Date("September 28, 2014")); // deadline
```

and the progress bar should show in percent the current status like "we are at 20%" till the end date.

The progress bar should be animated (on each refresh) from 0 - current status, for e.g. 20%.

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should visit odesk or freelance.com

Comment: I've posted the answer, it's more like "letmedoitforyou.com" ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Hints :

you should be able to calculate the difference between two dates using this code :

```
var diff = Math.abs(new Date() - new Date(dateStr.replace(/-/g,'/')));
```

and the date should be in numbers. Then you should calculates the difference between the creation date of the page :

```
var Vdiff = Math.abs(new new Date(beginningdateStr.replace(/-/g,'/')) - new Date(dateStr.replace(/-/g,'/')));
```

then progressbar value should be equal to `(diff*100)/Vdiff`

Answer (score 0):

I've got a working code, it's based on jquery thermometer.js plugin, it's vertical progress bar with 2 dates and animation.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aluviana/qap63un2/5/